# Google Document AI - Demo vs Rest API setup

Tags: cloud-document-ai

Regarding Document AI, there seems to be an inconsistency between the "Try it out" page and the actual result from the REST API. We need the tables to be parsed nicely like in the demo, but performance is lesser from the REST API.

Here is how to reproduce.

======Try it out page======

DemoConfiguration.png shows the General processor was used.
DemoResult.png shows the nice tables produced for the line items.

======From the API======
Our General processor was setup using the doc.

Code taken from provided documentation in Python and using the same SampleDocument.pdf, the code in TestSampleDocumnet.py (see attachment).
When looping through the line items table using the table parsing documentation, you'll notice lines are skipped or merged together.

---

Please notice I do not use the TableBoundHint  structure suggested here for 2 reasons:

1. I do not know in advance where the tables are.
2. It's not supported/properly documented for usage with v1, only v1beta2.

Answer (score 0):

The API behavior and output has changed significantly between `v1beta2` and the current GA version `v1`. It's recommended to use the [`v1` API](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest) for all activity going forward.

The [Form Parser](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#processor_form-parser) is designed for recognizing form fields as key-value pairs and tables in documents. The documentation has been recently updated to show how to handle the processing response from the Form Parser to recognize Tables in the document.

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response#forms_and_tables

**UPDATE:** The [Demo](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/drag-and-drop) in the documentation has been updated to use the `v1` API and provide separate options for the OCR and Form Parser processors